# CDIの@RequestScopedで作成したビジネスロジックをjBatchから呼び出す方法

Tags: java, java-ee

JavaEEをベースにWebアプリケーションを作成しています。
ビジネスロジックや、データアクセス用のクラスに、`@RequestScpoed`を使って実装していたのですが、jBatchからは、`@Dependent`または、`@ApplicationScoped`しか呼び出せないことがわかり、困っています。

以下の様なエラーが出てしまいます。

> 重大:   Failure in Read-Process-Write Loop  
>   com.ibm.jbatch.container.exception.BatchContainerRuntimeException: org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped

以下のページに参考になりそうな情報があったのですが、
解決方法がわかりませんでした。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847287/cdi-simulate-request-scope

Comment: (jBatch使用経験が無いので用語など誤っているかもしれません)[こちらの発言](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847287/cdi-simulate-request-scope#comment51669293_31847287)の意図するところは、Batchlet等実装クラス(これは現状も`@Dependent`なCDI Beanかと思います)で直接`@RequestScoped`なCDI Beanをinjectするのではなく、一旦`@Stateless`なEJB Beanをinjectし、そのEJB BeanでCDI Beanをinjectすればうまくいった、ということだと思います。
/ ちなみに、jBatchの中で`@RequestScoped`を使用するとどうなるのでしょうか(おそらく例外になると思うのですが、どんな例外メッセージが出力されるのでしょうか)。「`@Dependent`または、`@ApplicationScoped`しか呼び出せない」という状況が少し不思議だな、と感じて検索してみたのですがヒットしなかったもので…

Comment: 解説して頂いた通り、途中にEJBを挟むことで、@RequestScopedのCDIをInjectできました。

Comment: エラーは以下の様なものが出ます。  重大:   Failure in Read-Process-Write Loop 
com.ibm.jbatch.container.exception.BatchContainerRuntimeException: org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped

Comment: ありがとうございます。私も気になってもう少し調べてみたのですが、[こちら](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/batch-processing005.htm#BCGIFJBB)にjBatchとCDIの連携について言及がありました。
この文面だけを見た限りでは、batch artifactを`@Dependent`なCDI Beanで作成し、JSLにはEL名で宣言しておけば、CDI利用時の制限は特に無い、ように読めますね…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WildFly10.1.0.Final(jBatch実装: jberet 1.2.1, CDI実装: Weld 2.3.5)で試してみました:

batch artifact の中で `@RequestScoped` なCDI Beanをinjectした場合、次のような例外が送出されました。

```
10:15:01,645 WARN  [org.jberet] (Batch Thread - 3) JBERET000001: Failed to run batchlet org.jberet.job.model.RefArtifact@730db889: org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:689)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.getIfExists(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:90)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$CachingContextualInstanceStrategy.getIfExists(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:165)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.getIfExists(ContextualInstance.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:83)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.getInstance(ProxyMethodHandler.java:125)
    at jp.himeji_cs.javaee.hello_jbatch.MyRequestScopedBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.sayHello(Unknown Source)
    at org.javaee7.batch.batchlet.simple.MyBatchlet.process(MyBatchlet.java:61)
    at org.jberet.runtime.runner.BatchletRunner.run(BatchletRunner.java:72)
    at org.jberet.runtime.runner.StepExecutionRunner.runBatchletOrChunk(StepExecutionRunner.java:229)
    at org.jberet.runtime.runner.StepExecutionRunner.run(StepExecutionRunner.java:147)
    at org.jberet.runtime.runner.CompositeExecutionRunner.runStep(CompositeExecutionRunner.java:164)
    at org.jberet.runtime.runner.CompositeExecutionRunner.runFromHeadOrRestartPoint(CompositeExecutionRunner.java:88)
    at org.jberet.runtime.runner.JobExecutionRunner.run(JobExecutionRunner.java:60)
    at org.wildfly.extension.batch.jberet.impl.BatchEnvironmentService$WildFlyBatchEnvironment$1.run(BatchEnvironmentService.java:243)
    at org.wildfly.extension.requestcontroller.RequestController$QueuedTask$1.run(RequestController.java:497)
    at org.jberet.spi.JobExecutor$3.run(JobExecutor.java:161)
    at org.jberet.spi.JobExecutor$1.run(JobExecutor.java:99)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
```

今回ServletコンテナからjBatchを実行したのですが、jBatch自体は別スレッド(Servletとは別コンテキスト)で処理されるようです。
(これが仕様からみて当然な挙動なのか、実装依存の話なのかは分かりませんでした。おそらく[JSR-352](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=352) specの"10.5 Batch Artifact Loading", "11 Job Runtime Lifecycle"あたりが関係しそうでしたが理解できていません…)
そこでは[request contextがアクティブ化されていない](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#request_context)のでinjectしようとすると例外が発生する、ということだと思います。

解決策のひとつとしては、request contextがアクティブ化される条件(先に示した[CDI spec](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#request_context)参照)下で実行するようにする、というのが考えられ、[質問文中リンク先で示されている、EJB Beanを用いる](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847287/cdi-simulate-request-scope#comment51669293_31847287)というのはこれに当たるでしょう。
もうひとつ別の解決策としては、自前ででアクティブ化する、という方法も考えられます。

- [java - WebSocket endpoint and CDI injection: No active contexts for scope RequestScoped - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42440851/websocket-endpoint-and-cdi-injection-no-active-contexts-for-scope-requestscoped/42442415#42442415)

この例ではWeld依存になりますが、上記リンク先で示されているインタセプタ`RequestContextInterceptor`を利用する(※ただしそのままでは上手く動かなかったので[Priorityを設定](https://github.com/yukihane/hello-jbatch/blob/13ef3b2d1934cfcc7ffbea6a3ac22725d244ee42/src/main/java/jp/himeji_cs/javaee/hello_jbatch/scope_controll/RequestContextInterceptor.java#L18))ことで`Batchlet`内でも`@RequestScoped`なCDI Beanをinjectできるようになりました。

```
@Dependent
@Named
public class MyBatchlet extends AbstractBatchlet {

    @Inject
    private MyRequestScopedBean myBean;

    @RequestContextOperation
    @Override
    public String process() {
        System.out.println(myBean.sayHello());

        return BatchStatus.COMPLETED.toString();
    }
}
```

今回検証に使ったソースは[こちら](https://github.com/yukihane/hello-jbatch)になります。

Answer (score 0):

jBatchから呼び出す入口をEJB（@Stateless）にして、その中で、@RequestScopedの既存のビジネスロジックを呼び出す様にしたら、動作しました。